# How to send some button value while logged in in Django?

Tags: python, django, csrf

I have a problem, I want to submit while logged in and pass value of button *(Some_value)* further.

Without using csrf in form, debug mode suggests me using csrf_token, when I do - like in following code, it gives me *HTTP ERROR 405*

**In HTML**

```
        <td align="right">
            <form action="reg_this" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <button name="team_reg" value="Some_value">send this</button>
            </form>
```

**In views.py**

```
class Confirmation(BaseView):
    template_name = "my_page.html"

    @csrf_exempt
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        print(context)
        return context
```

**In urls.py**

```
 url('^app/reg_this', views.Confirmation.as_view(template_name="my_page.html")),
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using button type attribute and give its value as submit

```
<button name="team_reg" value="Some_value" type="submit">send this</button>
```